# Unable to Import Data into Existing Azure SQL Database; Success Only After Deleting Data

Tags: .net, azure-sql-database

I am currently working on importing data into an existing Azure SQL Database using the Azure Management Libraries for .NET. The issue I am encountering is that when I attempt to import data into a non-empty database, I receive an error stating that it is not possible to import data into an existing database.

[Error SQL71659: Data cannot be imported into target because it contains one or more user objects. Import should be performed against a new empty database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXhgR.png)

If I manually delete all the data from the database and then perform the import operation, it succeeds.

I am looking for guidance on whether there is a way to import data directly into an existing non-empty database using the Azure Management Libraries for .NET. Alternatively, I am interested in a method or workaround that would allow me to automate both the deletion of data and the import operation in a single step since I currently have to execute these steps separately.

Additional Information:

I am using the Azure Management Libraries for .NET for managing Azure SQL Database. Link to the repository with the sample code: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/sql-database-dotnet-manage-import-export-db

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Could you provide the code what you have tried? It will be more understandable to know about the error if you provide with [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Balaji I have used the same code provided in  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/sql-database-dotnet-manage-import-export-db

Comment: @KaranVyas, I'm using different libraries please check this [image](https://i.imgur.com/ToDsX74.png), If this reaches your requirement, I can share full answer in the below.

Comment: @Balaji I am open to trying different approaches and libraries. The current library I am using allows me to perform export and import operations in Azure SQL database to/from the blob storage container. It provides the same functionalities as Azure Portal. What I am currently lacking is importing the backup file into an existing non empty database.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import data into a `Non-Empty` Azure SQL Database. For more information, check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-import?view=sql-server-ve). This is the reason for the occurrence of the error.  You can only import `bacpac` file in the newly created or empty database.

To import a `bacpac` file from Azure Blob, you can follow the approach shown below:

- Open `Azure SQL Server` and click on `Import database`.

[image]

- Select the db from Azure Storage that you want to deploy into the Azure SQL Server and fill in the details in the respective fields as shown below.
  [image]
- It will be deployed successfully into the Azure SQL Server by creating a new database.
  [image]
- The `bacpac` file is stored as a new db in the Azure SQL server, as you can see below:
  [image]